# How safe and stable is carrying out a system restore?

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore

OS > Windows Vista Home Premium

Ive carried out a system restore from the start of the week. My system seems to be running fine but I was wondering if there are any risks from carrying out this procedure.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there are no or very low risks involved. A system restore is safe, I did it several times when some buggy driver messed up my system and a system restore saved me.